# How to get conditional statement using System.CodeDom like ? : not if-else block

Tags: c#, code-generation, codedom

Hi I am looking for little help here, I know I could generate code something like this

```
 var conditionMethod = new CodeConditionStatement(conditionStmt);
      conditionMethod.TrueStatements.Add(new CodeAssignStatement(new CodePrimitiveExpression(code1),
        new CodePrimitiveExpression(null)));

      conditionMethod.FalseStatements.Add(new CodeAssignStatement(new CodePrimitiveExpression(code1),
        new CodePrimitiveExpression(5)));
```

Which is result in proper IF and ELSE block, what I am looking for having something like this

```
var result = condtion?result1:result2;
```

How to generate this type of code from CodeDom, any help  is appreciated. thanks

Comment: “? .. : ..” _doesn’t exist_ in MSIL. It’s a C# “convenience” syntax that maps down to primitive conditionals. In short, it’s no different when compiled than explicitly typed out - X result; if (condition) { result = result1; } else { result = result2; }

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks, actually I am trying to change some old code, where LHS is not available in said method. So I have to create RHS side and using CodeAssignStatement I combine it, so normal IF/ELSE block would not help.. thanks for your tip